# Where does a program install on linux?

Tags: linux, installation

I want to know the procedure of installation and uninstallation on Linux?

Are there any log file that logs these procedure?

For example, I am installing Netbeans IDE on Linux. I want to know where are the files of this IDE?  I want to know where the folder is that contain programs that installed on Linux.

For example, if you install Netbeans IDE, then you can see somethink like below on a file :

> programName date time usr
>
> netbeans-7ml 06/08/2011 8:3:00 root

Comment: Depends on the program and package manager. The files will be all over the place as well.

Comment: Duplicate of [how does a program install on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964611/how-does-a-program-install-on-linux). Please don't double-post.

Answer (score 11):

Depends on the Linux flavor (distro) that you are running but typically programs get installed on `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

You can `cd` to the `/usr/bin` directory and then do `ls -la | more` and you'll see all the "executable" files there.

Answer (score 7):

While is true that every distro has it's own methods there is a standard (or attempt for it) filesystem hierarchy which is worth reading:

http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html

There you'll see where should go the system binaries, the system libraries, why no_system binaries go some times to /usr/bin and some other times to /usr/local/bin, what is /bin, what the heck is /usr/sbin, where should be located the documentation of each package, why settings are placed in /etc, what is the /var directory, why packages which are not from your distro commonly are installed in /opt, etc...

Again, It's worth reading.

Comment: Very helpful link, thanks! Would have been nice if you had summarized the relevant sections in your answer, as that is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are different methods depending on the linux distribution -- On Redhat/Fedora the the installation is done though RPM packages, which then are distributed for update and installed mostly using YUM -- How to create a [RPM is documented here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package)

On debrian/ubutu systems the equivalent is a DEB package which is distributed and installed though apt-get.   How to create a [DEB package is documented here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html)

If all you want is your own program which you have compiled on your own system yo be accessible for you to execute, then either just setup the PATH to include the directory where your executable is located, or copy the executable to /usr/bin or (/usr/local/bin if that is part of the PATH already)