# Linux - Where all programs are stored?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Where is a typical Linux program installed](https://superuser.com/questions/284388/where-is-a-typical-linux-program-installed)
>   [Where does a program install on linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/319730/where-does-a-program-install-on-linux)

In Windows it's clear - Program files - all programs are there. But where are programs in linux stored?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the executables are in /usr/bin/ or /usr/local/bin. Linux programs generally use resources in other folders too, such as shared libraries in /usr/lib/ or /usr/local/lib.